# xpath - libxml2dom insert element to the dom?

Tags: python, xpath, libxml2

A specific question regarding xpath, python, libxml2dom

Assume the following test html

How can one create python/xpath logic to insert an element in the dom before the tr associated with the xpath="//tr/td[@class='foo']"

I know there are associated methods for libxml2dom to accomplish this.. but I can't find docs/examples on how to do this!

thanks..

```
<html>
<body>
<tr>
<td class="foo">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="foo">
</td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

i'd like this.. where a "div" is added around the td/td..

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<tr>
<td class="foo">
</td>
</tr>
</div>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<div>
<tr>
<td class="foo">
</td>
</tr>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

pointers/comments.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, documentation for libxml2's Python bindings is pretty sparse. Anyway, this is how I would do it...

```
import libxml2
html = '<html><body><tr><td class="foo"></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td class="foo"></td></tr></body></html>'
doc = libxml2.parseDoc(html)
for elem in [xeval.parent for xeval in doc.xpathEval('//tr/td[@class="foo"]')]:
    # Create a new div element
    newdiv = libxml2.newNode('div')
    # Copy current node
    node_copy = elem.copyNode(1)
    # Append current node copy to new div element
    newdiv.addChild(node_copy)
    # Replace current node with new div
    elem.replaceNode(newdiv)
```

Printing *doc* then gives you:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html><body><div><tr><td class="foo"/></tr></div><tr><td/></tr><div><tr><td class="foo"/></tr></div></body></html>
```

I know, there's an XML root element sitting there - I'm sure someone can dream up a way of getting rid of it!